# why background-image property is not working?

Tags: html, css

I've `index.html` file and `img` folder residing in the same directory,
I want to have the background image in  `div` with `.img1`.

so I'm doing something like this :

**Index.html**

```css
.img1 {
  background-image: url("img/bg-header.jpg");
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="img1">
  <div class="ptext">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <div class="home-inner text-center">
        <h2 class="display-4 text-center">PULSES</h2>
        <br>
        <p> HALUTZIM 26 TEL AVIV<br><br><a href="tel:+972-50-4410600">+4410600</a></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="arrow">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

this should set the background image of the div, but it is not working ?

**Note:**

As I mentioned `index.html` `style.css` and `img` folder are residing in the same directory, I've images inside `img` folder.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Please help thank You

Comment: Make sure .img1 isn't a 0x0 px div

Comment: No its not ! @Musa

Comment: try trouble shooting by by removing background-attachment property, then i would double check spelling (i know its silly).  Check z-index as well - also try just using background

Comment: I tried it , but not working @VladimirMujakovic

Comment: Just to test it out can you place an image tag on the page with the same source you have in css, just to see if the image will render, sorry if you tried this

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic, Yes I tried this dear

Comment: and that is working there , but not from `css` with the same path

Comment: @contributor can you provide the link to your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to render the image as an in-line image in your page using  tag just to confirm that the path is ok. If the path is ok, check the div's width and height then play around with `background-postion` property.

If still not working, post your html head.

Comment: Vieira deCarvalho , but one problem I'm facing is when I write `position: fixed`, it get the image , for `position:relative` it is not working, please help

Answer (score -3):

I would try background-image: url("../img/bg-header.jpg");

Complementing my answer with Wayne's good explanation in the comments below:

"the relative path from a CSS file is based on its location. Thus the same CSS file can be used for HTML files in different locations. The css file is not in the same directory as the html. Hence ../ or /img/bg-header.jpg if the /img/ is off the root www directory."

Comment: why would you do that, why you are going back by `../`

Comment: try displaying it inline, just to check if it is a path issue

Comment: @contributor "In inline with the same path it is working," I believe that is why Pedro suggested the change. https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/ the relative path from a CSS file is based on its location. Thus the same CSS file can be used for HTML files in different locations. The css file is not in the same directory as the html. Hence ../ or /img/bg-header.jpg if the /img/ is off the root www directory.

Comment: @contributor Wayne - Exactly. And the guy who got the best answer just read these comments and answered hehe. I got -3 downvotes >_<